# What should I use `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate <value>` for, when authenticating using Kerberos?

Tags: c++, security, kerberos, mit-kerberos

I have a web server than returns a `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate` HTTP header (no `<value>`), which indicates the client should authenticate using Kerberos.

Then the client generates a Kerberos token as follows (the input token is empty):

```
gss_init_sec_context(
                    &minor_status, GSS_C_NO_CREDENTIAL, (gss_ctx_id_t*)context, (gss_name_t)name, GSS_KRB5_MECHANISM,
                    request_flags, 0, GSS_C_NO_CHANNEL_BINDINGS, (gss_buffer_desc*)input_token_x, nullptr,
                    (gss_buffer_desc*)output_token, &return_flags, nullptr);
```

This token can only be used for a single request (why?) for which the server responds with a `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate <value>` HTTP header, like:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate YIGZBgkqhkiG9xIBAgICAG+BiTCBhqADAgEFoQMCAQ+iejB4oAMCARKicQRv3w2k6UrZ+MQ2wnUaWFxGjiWXi/QHrcdcjlklMW7uCgYUsaLqwO6ihBIxjfSSSHxmMm6JMwbf/0xrN8gMq5D9By9/5YKIOzQWKjwm73CfkrvMAq+Ns0StFfXxkx3rFm2u0OBpuaB77TubvLsMap45
```

Now what should this `<value>` be utilized for?

Should I run `gss_init_sec_context()` with an empty input token before every web request, similar to how it's done in [requests-kerberos](https://pypi.org/project/requests-kerberos/)?

It seems wrong thus... I would like to obtain a long-lived token. How is the `<value>` normally utilized?

Comment: It is all in the [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4559). No you don't need to re-negotiate every time, you can use the token returned by the final for as long as it's valid.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Thank you. But how to I see how long it's valid? Also, when do I know whether it's "the final"? The token initially returned by `gss_init_sec_context` is accepted by the API for one request only. Why isn't it accepted for more than once?

Comment: "how long it's valid?" I think there's an API for that but don't worry, when it ceases being valid, you will just get another authentication challenge. The final one is when you get a 200 response (this is also in the RFC).

Comment: Thank you! But having read the entire RFC, I'm still a bit confused. In the example (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4559#section-5), the client retrieves a new token using the `gss_init_sec_context` with an empty input? It's stated "*The client will obtain the user credentials using the SPNEGO GSSAPI*".  In the final one (HTTP 200), how is the token returned? I don't see any token, except another `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate <value>`. The RFC states, I should provide this to `gss_init_sec_context`, but again, how am I going to receive this token, you're referring to?

Comment: Do you know what is meant by "*It is not always possible to mutually authenticate the server before the HTTP operation.  POST methods are in this category.*"?

Comment: Finally, the token you're referring to, how is it supposed to be sent to the Windows IIS in succesive calls? In `Authorization` HTTP header? Should I specify "Negotiate" in front of the value?

Comment: (1) Not sure what you mean. You get a `401` with `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate <value>`, you pass the value to `gss_init_security_context`, you get the output toke, you sent it with the `Authorization: Negotiate <token>` request and wait for the next response. If the response is 401 with `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate <value>` again, you do it again. If the response is 200, it's the final one. *If* the final one has `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate <value>`, you pass it with `gss_init_security_context`, and if the result is OK, *the response can be used*.

Comment: (1 contd) If the resilt is not OK, it means the server failed mutual auth. If there is no `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate <value>` with the 200 response, then there is no mutual auth, the response can be used, and the last token you sent can be used again.

Comment: (2) It just means you shouldn't POST your data to an untrusted party. Authenticate first, with GET or whatever, then POST. (3) Yes, you always should specify "Negotiate" in front of the value.

Comment: I will write an answer.

Comment: It seems I was wrong, you cannot reuse the token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generate the initial token for an `Authorization: Negotiate` request by calling `gss_init_sec_context()` with no input token.

If the server returns a 401 with `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate <value>`, it means the negotiation has not finished yet. You call `gss_init_sec_context()` again, this time passing the value as the input token parameter (after decoding). You send the resulting token with another `Authorization: Negotiate` request. You do it until you either get `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate` with no data attached (meaning the negotiation has failed), or some other response, normally 200 but may be anything else like 301 (meaning the authorization has succeeded).

Some servers may be configured to require authentication with every request or once per connection. If the latter, the server will not send `WWW-Authenticate` with subsequent requests and you don't need to send any `Authorization`. The server will send `Persistent-Auth: true` if so. At any rate you cannot reuse the negotiation token. You either issue a new token for every request, or do not send any tokens after the initial one if Persistent-Auth is set to true.

You don't have to wait for `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate` to generate a token. If you know that the server uses this protocol, just send `Authorization: Negotiate <token>` right away.

Now you may get another `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate` with a token with a 200 response (or I presume other responses indicating success). This token is the server's mutual authentication token. If you get one, you should call `gss_init_sec_context()` with it yet another time. If `gss_init_sec_context()` returns a success, you are all set. Otherwise it means that *the client could not authenticate the server* (maybe the server was not set up correctly,  or someone is trying to impersonate it).

References:

1. [RFC 4559](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4559)
2. [Persistent-Auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-n2ht/84d276f8-3632-44e8-a2ff-b169c693049d)

Comment: Thank you so much for this information and explanation! Do you know of any examples in C/C++?

Comment: You say, you can’t reuse a token. So, how is a new token for the next  request generated? Should I use `gss_init_sec_context` yet again with an empty input token, or should I use material from the prior request?

Comment: It’s not strictly required to call `gss_init_sec_context` with the value of a HTTP 200 response, right? It’s only to ensure mutual authentication succeeded?

Comment: How do you see from the RFC that you should initially call `gss_init_sec_context` with an empty input token? In the second block of text, it would be helpful, if you mentioned the status code (401) for the `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate <value>` case. How do the server knows the client is authenticated in the case of `Persistent-Auth`?

Comment: 1. Libcurl is a good example. 2. Yes, gss_init_sec_context yet again with an empty input token. 3. You want to call it to make sure you are talking to the server you think you are talking to. 4. This is actually in GSSAPI RFC https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2744#section-5.19. With Persistent-Auth the client authenticates once per session.

Comment: Thank yet again for your excellent support! 2) How do you see from the RFC that tokens cannot be reused, and that you should use `gss_init_sec_context` for each request?

Comment: Isn't it extremely inefficient to call `gss_init_sec_context` prior to every request? I assume, it makes use of the principal's (user) TGT ticket for the domain to compute a TGS ticket, which is encoded and sent to the server? Normally, a TGS can be re-used for multiple requests, which is a major overhead? In essence, with this method of authentication, you need to make at least two HTTP requests for every HTTP request

Comment: I don't see it from the RFC, it's common sense. Reuse would open you to a replay attack. Inefficiency is relative and likely will be drowned by the network delays. You don't need two requests "If you know that the server uses this protocol, just send Authorization: Negotiate <token> right away".

Comment: Thanks again. Do you know what happens when you run `gss_init_sec_context`? Some people refer to it as a "Kerberos handshake", but is that true? Does that call involve network requests to other systems, or is it only running local using the TGT? Regarding common sense, you started by stating that you could reuse tokens, but corrected it later :)

Comment: I've accepted your answer :)

Comment: Wel common sense is apparently not that common :) gss_init_sec_context  shouldn't include any network requests, those are done when you perform Kerberos login (that's as far as I remember, I've not been working with Kerberos for a decade or so).

Comment: OK, then I assume `gss_init_sec_context` is a leightweight local operation. Final question, for POST and PUT requests, how would I generate the Kerberos token? If I generate a new token using `gss_init_sec_context` with an empty input token, and the server requires multiple steps of negotation, then I would end up with a HTTP 200 answer and the token would already be used, so cannot be re-used with POST/PUT?

Comment: If you get a 401, you resend your entire request with a new token, including the POST header and the body, until you get a 200. When you get a 200, it doesn't just mean the authentication has succeeded, it means your request has succeeded. In this case, whatever needs to be posted has been posted.

Comment: But the RFC states that I should not POST/PUT without first authenticating? Does that mean, I should start by sending a GET to the same endpoint? You wrote **(2) It just means you shouldn't POST your data to an untrusted party. Authenticate first, with GET or whatever**, do you mean I should initially do a GET, and if I get 401 (Negotiate), then do another POST/PUT with the new token? Can you describe what you mean by "authenticate first"?

Comment: Or should I first carry out a successful GET authentication (HTTP 200) with a new token generated by `gss_init_sec_context` (empty input token), then carry out the exact same for POST/PUT (new token of `gss_init_sec_context` (empty input token))?.

Comment: Hmm I don't think I have ever done a post with Kerberos so I'm not sure. The simplest way to check is to use an existing browser or Curl and see what it does (you can capture the headers with Wireshark or similar).

Comment: It looks like the RFC wants you to use POST/PUT but without the data for initial authentication, and not rely on getting 200. "The return status from the gss_init_security_context will indicate that the security context is complete". When this happens, you can resend the request with the final token and the data.

Comment: Can a security context be complete upon the first call to `gss_init_sec_context`? If that returns 1 (success), it’s safe to POST the data?

Comment: Do I know from the return status of `gss_init_sec_context` whether the context is complete, and the server will return success (HTTP 200)?

Comment: Yes you know by the return value (GSS_S_COMPLETE). The server may or may not return 200 depending on other conditions, but the authentication *is* complete.

Comment: But the problem is that once I receive 200, the token is already used, and cannot be used for the POST/PUT with body. How can I solve this problem? If I want to send a POST/PUT, I call `gss_init_sec_context()` with an empty input token, the use that token in call with `Negotiate <value>`, and then maybe receive 200 or 401. In case, I receive 200, the token is used. Does `GSS_S_COMPLETE` and `GSS_S_CONTINUE_NEEDED` means the resulting output token is final, and will be accepted by the server, without further negotiation?

Comment: Also, do you know whether a new security context should be created for all requests, i.e. do I need to call `gss_init_sec_context()` every time with `GSS_C_NO_CONTEXT`? I would like to reuse it if possible?

Comment: Also, the server does indeed return `Persistent-Auth: true`, but it doesn't say how I benefit from it? In case, I receive this header, can I then reuse tokens? It doesn't seem so from experimenting, so not sure the effect of this header

Comment: In any case, thanks for your support on my Kerberos journey so far. I wouldn't have got this far without your help. I'm grateful for it, and wish you the best

Comment: I don't think you can reuse it. It is cheap to call gss_init_sec_context anyway, it doesn't contact KDC or anything like that. If you receive Persistent-Auth: true, you don't reuse the token, you just don't send any further authorization header (in the current connection).

Comment: Ahh, nice. I have checked out libcurl as you suggested, but naturally they don't reuse the context, as Curl only performs a single request. How do you define **current connection**? HTTP is stateless, so the connection ends as soon as the client receives an anwer? https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/c44671ed431aa3d40819e59f63c471be158480a7/lib/krb5.c#L348

Comment: The connection is defined as the TCP connection.

Comment: Ahh, that ends as soon as the request is finished, at least in most scenarios. However, multiple requests can be sent over a single connection with HTTP 2.0, right? Do you know whether `GSS_S_COMPLETE` and `GSS_S_CONTINUE_NEEDED` mean the output token is final, so it can be used for the HTTP POST/PUT request, with no further HTTP 401 Negotiate <value> received? Otherwise, if I'm just waiting for HTTP 200 to know whether my request was accepted, I will never have the opportunity to send my HTTP POST/PUT with a body

Comment: "that ends as soon as the request is finished, at least in most scenarios" No.